# Wordpress child theme can't prevent parent theme error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, php-7

Trying to update a Wordpress instance to PHP 7.2 and I've got a parent theme that uses the deprecated `$this` in its functions.php.

```
function paperback_filter_page_templates( $page_templates, $this, $post ) {

    if( ! class_exists( 'Easy_Digital_Downloads' ) ) :
        unset( $page_templates['inc/edd/home-downloads.php'] );
    endif;

    return $page_templates;

}
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'paperback_filter_page_templates', 10, 3 );
```

I've been unsuccessful...

### 1: Overriding the function in the child theme's functions.php:

*(removing `$this` from the param and with higher priority `add_filter`)*

```
function paperback_filter_page_templates( $page_templates, $post ) {

  if( ! class_exists( 'Easy_Digital_Downloads' ) ) :
    unset( $page_templates['inc/edd/home-downloads.php'] );
  endif;

  return $page_templates;
}
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'paperback_filter_page_templates', 15, 2 );
```

### 2: Using a function that removes the filter in the child theme's functions.php:

```
function rm_paperback_filter_page_templates() {
  remove_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'paperback_filter_page_templates', 10);
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'rm_paperback_filter_page_templates', 15 );
```

*(have tried hooking this action into `init`, `setup_theme`, `after_setup_theme`...)*

I can remove the offending function from the parent theme to avoid a catastrophic php 7.2 upgrade for now (parent theme authors/company have been acquired so an update isn't coming) and I know to look for parent themes with pluggable functions from now on... but it'd be nice to know if a real fix is possible!